# Building R package from github: how to disable building vignettes?

Tags: r, github

I try to build [fork of R package](https://github.com/patcpsc/rredis) from github (this fork has a [fresh bugfix](https://github.com/bwlewis/doRedis/issues/10)). Unfortunatelly, the compilation fails on TeX being missed on my system when trying to build vignettes. I don't want to install loads of SW just to build vignettes I don't need. How can I disable building them?

This is how my compilation went:

```
> require(devtools)
> install_github("patcpsc/rredis")
Installing github repo rredis/master from patcpsc
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/patcpsc/rredis/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\DOCUME~1\Tomas\LOCALS~1\Temp\Rtmpolel1d/master.zip
Installing rredis
Installing dependencies for rredis:
RUnit
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RUnit_0.4.26.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 194763 bytes (190 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 190 Kb

package ‘RUnit’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas\Local Settings\Temp\Rtmpolel1d\downloaded_packages
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/i386/R" --vanilla CMD build "C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas\Local  \
  Settings\Temp\Rtmpolel1d\devtools42062762938\rredis-master" --no-manual --no-resave-data 

* checking for file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas\Local Settings\Temp\Rtmpolel1d\devtools42062762938\rredis-master/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'rredis':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ...Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/i386/Rscript" --vanilla --default-packages= -e "tools::buildVignettes(dir = '.', tangle = TRUE)"' had status 1
 ERROR
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
Calls: <Anonymous> -> texi2pdf -> texi2dvi
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, found it! I missed it as it is not listed in options of `install_github` function, but it accepts all the other options of `install` and `build` functions!

```
install_github("patcpsc/rredis", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

Comment: BTW this will be the default in the next version of devtools, which will be on its way to cran soon

Comment: `build_vignettes=F` is now the default