# Fail to build package when trying to install vignettes with install_github [R]

Tags: r, devtools

By default when one is using `install_github` function from `devtools` package in R the vignettes of the installed package are not build. I've seen this questio with an answer which shows how to build vignettes if one desires to 
[Building R package from github: how to disable building vignettes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821473/building-r-package-from-github-how-to-disable-building-vignettes).

I wrote a package with [such vignettes](https://github.com/MarcinKosinski/RTCGA/tree/master/vignettes) and but I recieve an error what installing directly from github like this:

```
> devtools::install_github("MarcinKosinski/RTCGA")
Downloading github repo MarcinKosinski/RTCGA@master
Installing RTCGA
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpCIboSY/devtools17de96523e5/MarcinKosinski-RTCGA-e47bdf6'  \
  --library='/home/mkosinski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2'  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘RTCGA’ ...
** R
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RTCGA)
> browseVignettes("RTCGA")
No vignettes found by browseVignettes("RTCGA")
> ?devtools::install_github
> devtools::install_github("MarcinKosinski/RTCGA", build_vignettes= TRUE)
Downloading github repo MarcinKosinski/RTCGA@master
Installing RTCGA
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD build  \
  '/tmp/RtmpCIboSY/devtools17de1905fc71/MarcinKosinski-RTCGA-e47bdf6'  \
  --no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpCIboSY/devtools17de1905fc71/MarcinKosinski-RTCGA-e47bdf6/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘RTCGA’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
Removed empty directory ‘RTCGA/ghPage’
Removed empty directory ‘RTCGA/inst’
* building ‘RTCGA_0.99.6.tar.gz’

'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpCIboSY/RTCGA_0.99.6.tar.gz'  \
  --library='/home/mkosinski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2'  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘RTCGA’ ...
** R
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file '/home/mkosinski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RTCGA/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing ‘/home/mkosinski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RTCGA’
* restoring previous ‘/home/mkosinski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RTCGA’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

When I build package from source locally there are no errors. Can anyone know what can be a cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    vig_list = tools::vignetteEngine(package = 'knitr')
    vweave <- vig_list[['knitr::knitr']][c('weave')][[1]]
    vtangle <- vig_list[['knitr::knitr']][c('tangle')][[1]]
    tools::vignetteEngine(pkgname, weave = vweave, tangle = vtangle,
                          pattern = "[.]Rmd$", package = pkgname)
    #register_vignette_engines(pkgname)
}
```

this function to `zzz.R` file in `R/` directory and `knitr` package to Dependencies in `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer.  Where did you get that code snippet from, though?

Comment: I actually don't remember. But I think I looked at the repository of someone smart for whom vignette builder works and copied it from. I think I had looked at github.com/hadley/dplyr

Comment: it does not work for me! I put it in a `misc.R` file which has all the `.onAttach` and other functions. Is mandatory to put this in `zzz.R`?