# Installing package fails when building vignettes ((..)/doc/index.html is missing)

Tags: r, r-package, vignette

I'm creating an R package with a vignette. However, when I try to install the package by using

```
 devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

an error occurs since it cannot find the file index.html in the doc folder. I thought this file would be automatically created, but apperently something goes wrong here. The error occuring is the following:

```
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
--quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/lnab/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpi0XLJ4/mecor_0.1.0.tar.gz"  \
--library="\\vf-d2-home/d2home$/lnab/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'mecor' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
converting help for package 'mecor'
finding HTML links ... done
mecor-package                           html  
uaetrial                                html  
uaetrial_cal                            html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
cannot open file '\\vf-d2-home/d2home$/lnab/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.4/mecor/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '\\vf-d2-home/d2home$/lnab/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.4/mecor'
* restoring previous '\\vf-d2-home/d2home$/lnab/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.4/mecor'
In R CMD INSTALL
```

My vignette .Rmd looks like this:

```
---
title: "Introduction to mecor"
author: "Linda Nab"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Introduction to mecor}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

I never build an R package before but search the internet for a solution for this problem for days but cannot find any. [This](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/705) seems to be the same problem but I cannot find the solution for the problem there. You can find my package [here](https://github.com/LindaNab/mecor).

Really hope someone could help me!

Comment: Try mapping the network drive, so the library is at something like `W://lnab/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.4/mecor` instead of the network share `\\vf-d2-home/d2hoem$/...`

Comment: Thanks. I mapped the network drive by changing the variable .libPaths to H:/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.4. Unfortunatelly, the same error is produced when installing the package.

Comment: In addition, the package check now also fails, producing the same error: 'Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file 'H:/mecor.Rcheck/mecor/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed'. Before changing the path of the library, the check did not fail.

Comment: It looks like you are building from the tar.gz which may have been built without vignette. Perhaps try run directly on the package: open mecor project file and run `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Comment: I succeeded in building the package with the vignettes! I had to remove the folder /inst where in the subfolder /doc the .R, .html and .Rmd of my vignette were stored after using `devtools::build_vignettes()` (I used this earlier when trying to find a solution for my problem). I guess mapping the network drive together with removing this folder ended up in a solution for my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: I still have this problem! The fixes I found do not work. In particular, I tried:
1.  Reverse the `.gitignore` as it was before the bug
2.  This: [`.onLoad()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286610/fail-to-build-package-when-trying-to-install-vignettes-with-install-github-r)
3.  This: [Hadley ..Rcheck](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/705)
Moreover, in my case the bug is happening only during the checks and not in the build!

Answer (score 5):

I had /inst/ and .git in my .Rbuildignore file. When I removed those two lines from .Rbuildignore the vignettes built properly.

Comment: I had this problem. In my .Rbuildignore file, someone, had put `inst/doc`. Once I removed it the error dissapeared.

Answer (score 3):

I also found and followed all the problems Garini notes on a comment:

1. Reverse the .gitignore as it was before the bug
2. This: `[.onLoad()][1]`
3. This: [Hadley ..Rcheck](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/705)

What worked for me was to check for other folders and files on the directory of the package and remove or ignore at building those folders that are not standard for an R package, for a summary of them see the index of [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). This is on line with the Hadley proposed solution. Maybe is a folder or file created by the vignette or while developing the package.

In my case I had a `build` folder I didn't realize it was there.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a few days, but in my case it worked once I removed a folder called "build". I am happy now!
Previously, my check worked but not my install.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, I made the dumb mistake of adding `doc` to `.Rbuildignore`. That generated the same error described here. Removing `doc` from `.Rbuildignore` solved the issue for me.